# Manipulating the order of elements in an array of references in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting, database

I'm working on implementing an image album and would like an elegant solution for storing the order of its images. The Album model holds an array of references to Images as follows:

```
// Example album
{
    _id: 12345
    images: [ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2), ObjectId(3)]
}

// Example image
{
    _id: 1
    title: My Picture
    author: Me
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to handle an order update in the database. For example, let's say I'd like to update the array of images from:

`[ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2), ObjectId(3)]`

to

`[ObjectId(3), ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2)]`

I'm wondering whether 1) I can directly reorganize an array of references via an update, or 2) if I can, how I can go about actually accessing each element in the array to dictate the new order.

Actually, this solution might be quite useless because the array could be populated asynchronously. An alternative solution would be to ignore what I'm asking for entirely, and store the order of each image individually as follows:

```
// Image
{
    _id: 1
    title: My Picture
    author: Me
    position: 2    // like this
}
```

This way when I pull down an array of images asynchronously, all I have to do is sort by each image's `position` field.

A downside to this strategy is that as the number of images gets sufficiently large, reordering will become quite costly. Moving the final element of a 100-length array to the very beginning would require that I update every single image's position value in the database.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of elements in array remains the same as it was persisted.

To change the order, update the array with the order you like. E.g.:

```
db.album.update({_id:1}, {$set:{images:[ObjectId(3), ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2)]}});
```

Comment: This is great to know, but will the order be preserved when I _populate_ those references? Assuming the populate method occurs asynchronously

Comment: Not sure what *populate* means in this context, but any document update is atomic. If you fear of conflicts with simultaneous updates, you need to implement incremental versioning of the document.

Comment: So before sending the array of images to the client simply as references, I want to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) them first with the each image's data. I'm unsure whether this population occurs asynchronously and whether the order of images becomes randomized.

Comment: I realize at this point I'm asking a new question: whether I can populate and deliver the array of references _in the order that they are stored_ to the client. This isn't fair, because you very helpfully answered my original question as to whether it's possible to alter the order of references in an array. Answer accepted!

Comment: Frankly, I would write a simple test to confirm order is preserved, rather than rely on answers from the web. It is quicker, more reliable, and will guarantee it does not silently regress after upgrade of one of the coponents.

Comment: You're right. I was also just wondering whether there are best practices when it comes to storing datasets like these. I thought maybe storing the order according to an array is not the best answer